# How do I deploy a Django or PHP website via Juju?

Tags: juju, webapps

This question may be a bit basic, but I have read the documentation here [https://jujucharms.com/docs/](https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/)

I understand how I deploy the charms(apps) to a service. But if I want to deploy a django app or php website to my services how do I do this on Juju?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is still done via a charm who's purpose is dedicated to hosting such an app.

ex)

`django`: http://jujucharms.com/python-django

`node.js`: http://jujucharms.com/node-app

Comment: So I load a django charm and then ftp to the charm location my files?

Comment: The documentation for using the django charm is in the page that I linked.